# How to open VK app from my ios app

Tags: ios, vk

I want to open my public page in vk app (if it is installed). How can I manage to do that

Here's the same trick with facebook

```
- (IBAction)facebook:(id)sender{
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/1425897281000202"]]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/1425897281000202"]];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/1425897281000202"];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
    else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
         openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/GooodApps"]];
    }
}
```

Thanx!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hi it should help you :)

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"vk://vk.com/ХХХ"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: Do you know perhaps of a similar solution for the Android app ?

Comment: I can be wrong, but this URL schema should also work for android.

Comment: I tried. It didn't, even though the other social networks apps URIs are identical . :(  I've made a post about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27043676/878126

Comment: Hmm... strange, Ok I can ask how my android friends implemented this, on the next week.

Comment: I wonder where they've found it. I don't speak Russian, and it's quite hard for me to search there for this information. Thank you.

Comment: I speak Russian, but it was difficult to find this URL schema even for me :D Sure, no problem)

Comment: Hi again, my android friend told me that he has exception using this URL schema, maybe android VK application doesn't support it(( but he give me this link https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk, maybe it will help you.

Comment: They answered me, so I told them to put the answer on SO, so that I could thank them. Anyway, thank you for your help !

Answer (score 10):

This works for me in Swift:

```
let appURL = NSURL(string: "vk://vk.com/id\(user.vkID)")!
let safariURL = NSURL(string: "vk.com/id\(user.vkID)")!

if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(appURL){
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(appURL)
} else {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(safariURL)
}
```

Comment: For groups use "vk://vk.com/clubXXXXXX" where XXXXXX=id.

Comment: let safariURL = NSURL(string: "https://vk.com/id\(user.vkID)")!
That works better)

Answer (score 0):

```
let appURL = NSURL(string: "vk://vk.com/id1")!
let safariURL = NSURL(string: "vk.com/id1")!

if UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(appURL){
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(safariURL))
}
```